# How to create a random range for enemies to appear?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a game where hero should jump over the enemies using Sprite Kit and Swift. I have 4 types of them but they're basically the same. When I coded appearance of enemies I thought it would be ok if they could appear in group but now I see that it's not very nice. How can I make a random range between enemies to appear? It should provide enough space for hero to land from a jump at least. I tried but end up with something bizarre.
That's how I'm spawning them:

```
func random() -> UInt32 {
var time = UInt32(60)..<UInt32(200)
return time.startIndex + arc4random_uniform(time.endIndex - time.startIndex + 1)
}
```

Then I have different file for appearance:

```
class EnemyAppear {
var nowAppear = false
var waitToAppear = UInt32(0)
var appearInterval = UInt32(0)
init(nowAppear:Bool, waitToAppear:UInt32, appearInterval:UInt32) {
    self.nowAppear = nowAppear
    self.waitToAppear = waitToAppear
    self.appearInterval = appearInterval
}

func shouldRun() -> Bool {
    return self.appearInterval > self.waitToAppear
}
```

}
then I have a function to run them on screen

```
func enemyRun() {
    for(enemy, enemyAppear) in self.enemyStatus {
    var thisPet = self.childNodeWithName(enemy)!
        if enemyAppear.shouldRun() {
            enemyAppear.waitToAppear = random()
            enemyAppear.appearInterval = 0
            enemyAppear.nowAppear = true
        }
```

And then for each enemy I have a "Status"

```
var enemyStatus:Dictionary<String,EnemyAppear> = [:]    


enemyStatus["mouse"] = EnemyAppear(nowAppear: false, waitToAppear: random(), appearInterval: UInt32(0))
```

I can't understand how to make them appear just like that but with an empty space between each other and where to put it.

Comment: Put it in your update method.  If timesincelastenemy > (random gen number bw 3-10 seconds) then spawn another enemy.  You can make it so it has to be higher than a certain number of seconds so there is a gap.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't get it. Can you post example of code?

Comment: I mean, what is that "timesincelasteneny" thing? If it's a function then I don't understand what it stands for

Comment: Look up raywenderlich.com  His early examples show how to use the update and updateWithTimeSinceLast which runs every frame which lets you check objects current state at that point.  From there, you just spawn an enemy every so often.

Comment: can you post a link to this? I couldn't find it on raywenderlich site :(